Linearizing cone (constrained optimization)
I have a problem in understanding the linearizing cone. Given an admissible set $\Omega$, characterized by equality and inequality constraints $c_i(x)$, the linearizing cone at x is given by $L_\Omega(x) = \{ d | d^T\nabla c_i(x) = 0$ for equality, $ d^T\nabla c_i(x) \geq 0 $ for inequality$\}$. Now it states, that the tangent cone at x is a subset of the linearizing cone and they are equal, if LICQ holds. My problem is, for the two equality constraints $c_1(x) = x_1 - x_2 $, $c_2 = x_1 + x_2 -1$, the only feasible point is $ x = (0,5 , 0,5)$, so the tangent cone should be $T_\Omega(x) = \{(0,5,0,5)\}$. The gradients are $\nabla c_1(x)^T= (1,-1)$ and $\nabla c_2(x)^T = (1,1)$. Therefore LICQ holds and the linearizing cone is empty. Where is my misunderstanding here? Should the tangent cone also be empty and why?

In your situation, both the tangent cone and the linearizing cone equal the set $$ \{ (0,0) \}.$$ Note that this is not the empty set.

Thank you for the answer. I get why the linearizing cone is ${(0,0)}$ but not why the tangent cone. (0,0) isn't even admissible don't I need a sequence, which becomes admissible at some point? Or is it, since the only sequence, which is admissible is at some point (0,5,0,5) and the direction between x an (0,5,0,5) is (0,0)?

It depends on your definition of the tangent cone, but yes, the direction is just $(0,0)$.
